# get_post_meta() doesn't allow email

Tags: themes, post-meta

I have a WordPress theme in which employers can post a job that is available in their company with all the requirements details and apply link and one job page gets created where those who are looking for a job can apply by clicking an apply button the job applicant is redirected to an external URL but I want to make some changes whenever an employer posts a job if he wants to receive job application on there EMAIL Address they can put the email address whenever a job applicant click on apply button mailto option popup but there is an issue I am facing whenever employer put an email to receive job applications on the job page apply button I someone click on apply button it's taking to the domain of the email like the part after @ sign.

`$apply_action = get_post_meta($job_id, 'job_action', true);`

May I know is this because of the `get_post_meta()` method or if there could be another reason?
Please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.